# Web API error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API and using the get methods in fiddler with some sample data in the table, I can get data from it.

When I try to insert a new record using a post method, I get the error:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Members'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

The thing is, I am actually supplying the value for `Id` in the JSON string. I am copying the json string I get from the get/id method exactly and just changing the Id.

I do have a column on the table called `Id` which is set to not allow nulls, and is NOT set to auto increment. This is because the requirements of the system only require that it be present and unique. It doesn't have to be sequential. So I want the person inserting to be able to supply their own id.

I don't understand why this error is coming up, as I am supplying all the data required.

Here is the database:

[image]

and here is my JSON string:

```
{
"Id":687,
"FirstName":"auto",
"EMail":"auto",
"Eligible":true,
"InsertLogtime":"2015-07-21T00:51:59.917"
}
```

This is the server side code: Apologies for not including it. When I step into this in debugger, the members class is actually initialised with an Id.

```
// POST api/Members
[ResponseType(typeof(Members))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMembers(Members members)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    db.Members.Add(members);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = members.Id }, members);
}
```

[image]

The Members class, as requested:

```
public partial class Members
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Eligible { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertLogtime { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the outermost exception stack trace...

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Xyz.Service.Controllers.MembersController.PostMembers(Members members) in c:\Repositories\Xyz\Xyz.Service\Controllers\MembersController.cs:line 41
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I'd really appreciate any help finding the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the code that actually handles the POST/PUT request on the server side? Just because you're sending JSON data with an ID in it does not mean that the server is doing anything with it

Comment: I just inserted it now, apologies and thanks.

Comment: where is the Members class????

Comment: I just inserted it now, apologies and thanks. It was auto generated by EF.

Comment: The members class is auto generated by EF from database. So id imagine that if it was required then it would be there. But not sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: your error message says table 'xyz' was that the actual table??

Comment: I updated it, originally it read a big long name so I just typed xyz instead. But it did refer to Members.

Comment: is the stacktrace avail?  does it have this controller call in it?  The code looks fine, wondering if your error is originating some place else, are you attached to a debugger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83815/discussion-between-francis-rodgers-and-t-mckeown).

Comment: that stacktrace still doesn't show where you invoked the SaveChanges()

Comment: To help debug, override the context SavingChanges method (I believe it's called), which fires right before save.  It contains all of the changes made, and you can visually inspect what is about to be sent to the database as a last verification...

Comment: @Brian, Im not sure how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, should clarify.  The dbcontext class has this.  It's a partial, so create a partial definition, override this method, and put a breakpoint in it.

Comment: @Brian - Was trying to do as you asked there. But DbContext doesnt seem to be a partial class. So I inherited it and override the SaveChanges method. Its now asking me to implement constructors ect. I wont know if I am doing it right, and would appreciate more help if possible.

Comment: Let's say you created an EF model named TEST.  It would create a TEST.Context.tt file.  In that, it generates a class that inherits from DbContext.  Create a class that defines partial with that name, not DbContext, as this is the specific implementation for your database.  Try this for savingchanges: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/12/ef-code-first-dbcontext-savingchanges/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to thank everyone here for their help... You were really great.

I finally found a solution that works after many hours of digging and given I use S/O for my own reference, I decided to just place it here. If anyone can think of an alternative that should have worked, I'd really like to hear about it.

Here is my solution:

In the EF Autogenerated Members class above:

```
public partial class Members
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Eligible { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertLogtime { get; set; }
}
```

Simply add this line:

```
public partial class Members
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Eligible { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertLogtime { get; set; }
}
```

I hope others find it helpful, and thanks everyone for your help again.

Comment: Wouldn't this (change) get overwritten any time you recompile the EF model, as this class is auto generated?

Answer (score 1):

For this object:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public CategoryEnum Category { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeNote> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I would see the same error you reported above when I tried to post the following from JavaScript:

```
{"recipeId":"","title":"test","category":1,"source":"test","instructions":"test"}
```

This caused the same null error that you have above.  `RecipeId` couldn't be null.  I fixed this for a short term by using `Public int? RecipeId{get;set;}`.  But that caused other problems.  I found a better solution.

I discovered that if I poseted the same data WITHOUT the `recipeId` field (like below) I didn't get the error.  The `recipeId` field was automatically populated in the database like it should be.

```
{"title":"test","category":1,"source":"test","instructions":"test"}
```

So I think the best fix is to exclude the ID field when posting data to your Web API function to add a record.

Hope this helps someone.